# Why is the image not showing up in the <title> division?

Tags: html, css

```css
*{
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 0vw;
}

nav{
    background-color: rgba(52, 52, 146, 0.829);
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    position:sticky;
    top: 0px;
}

ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style-type:none;

}

navl{
    border-color:red ;
    border-style: dotted;
    align-items: center;}
navr{
    border-color:red ;
    border-style: dotted;

}

main{
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
}
left{
    border-color: red;
    border-style: dotted;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: sticky;
    top: 45px;
}
center{
    border-color: red;
    border-style: dotted;
    width: 30vw;
    height:5000px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
right{
    border-color: red;
    border-style: dotted;
    width: 27vw;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

cover{
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: red;
    width: 60vw;
    height: 350px;
    background-image: url(cover.jpg);
}

content{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main{
    padding: 0px 60px;
    border:10px greenyellow double ;
}

interact{
    width: 60vw;
    height: 30px;
    border: 5px blue dashed;
}

feed{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.src{

}

body{
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
title{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <navl>
            <ul> 
                <li><img src="home.png" alt="logo"></li>
                <li class="src"><input type="search"></li>
                <li><img src="search.png" alt="hit"></li>
            </ul>
        </navl>

        <navr>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="party.png" alt="dp" style="width: 30px;" ></li>
                <li style="font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; color:white;padding-top: 6px;">Jason</li>
                <li>i1</li>
                <li>i2</li>
                <li>i3</li>
                <li>i4</li>
                <li>i5</li>
            </ul>
        </navr>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <left>
            <span>left</span>
        </left>
        <content>
            <cover>

            </cover>
            <interact>
                <l-int>

                </l-int>
                <r-int>

                </r-int>
            </interact>
            <feed>
                <center>
                    <post>
                        <title>
                            <img src="group.png" alt="" srcset="">
                        </title>

                    </post>
                </center>
                <right>
                    <span>right</span>
                </right>
            </feed>
        </content>
    </main>


</body>

</html>
```

Why is the image not showing up in the  division ? Instead the line--  -- is showing up in the box. I am trying to create a facebook clone. I am a beginner trying to learn web development. I think only the title `div` is relevant to this problem and not the entire code. 1st code is HTML while 2nd is `CSS` stylesheet

Comment: The `title` tag is not going to be rendered on the screen. You seem to be using many HTML tags that don't exist (`right`, `left`, `cover`). In general, you can't just make up your own HTML tags.

Comment: `<title>` is only permitted in `<head>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title. Perhaps you need a [HTML refresher](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML)

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/